# Not able to switch between applications?

Tags: 14.04, navigation

[image]

As shown in the picture, If I am on Google chrome application and wants to switch to any other application for ex: EClipse, Just clicking on the Eclipse icon does not launch Eclipse.

The same is happening when I do the alt-tab.

Not sure what is going on? Hope My question is clear.

Answer (score 1):

OK, totally rewriting this because I didn't understand the question. You're saying that if Chrome is active, then

1. Alt-Tab to switch applications doesn't work
2. Clicking the Launcher icon for other items doesn't work

I have no idea, but just to further understand it, can you click the Desktop or another non-Chrome window to get out of Chrome? And does normal use of Alt-Tab & the Launcher return until you use Chrome again? Or do you have to quit Chrome?

I can understand that Chrome might intercept Alt-Tab; VirtualBox does this and I just have to click on something else to move the focus out of VirtualBox, but I can click on the Launcher and it works just fine. I don't understand how Chrome is interfering with the mouse outside of its window.

Comment: It is not specific to Eclipse but with any other application. I am not able to switch to even terminal also from Google chrome.

Comment: Not an answer, but to get away from Chrome without restarting your computer, you could Ctl-Alt-F1 to get a non-X windows console, log in as yourself and run `$ pkill chrome`, then use `Alt-F7` to return to the X session. I tend to alternate between Firefox and Chrome depending on which seems less buggy today ;-)